# Can you help me with these two integrals?

Tags: integration, computer-algebra-systems, elliptic-integrals

These are three functions that I try to integrate by hand, however, I try many methods and they do not work. Can you help me with that?

The first function is:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- C\cos(t)}^3}dt\qquad \text{with } 0 < C <1$$

The second function is:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi } \frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{1- C \cos(t)}}dt \qquad \text{with } 0 < C <1$$

The third function is:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi } \frac{\cos(t)}{\sqrt{1- C \cos(t)}^3}dt \qquad \text{with } 0 < C <1$$

I have tried finding the answer through Maple, however, I could not understand the answer. Here is the answer for the three functions.
The first one is:
$$\,{\frac {-4}{\sqrt {C+1} \left( -1+C \right) }{\it EllipticE}
 \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {C}}{\sqrt {C+1}}} \right) }$$

The second one is:
$$\,{\frac {-4}{\sqrt {C+1}C} \left( C{\it EllipticE} \left( {\frac {
\sqrt {2}\sqrt {C}}{\sqrt {C+1}}} \right) -{\it EllipticK} \left( {
\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {C}}{\sqrt {C+1}}} \right) +{\it EllipticE}
 \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {C}}{\sqrt {C+1}}} \right)  \right) }$$

And the third one is:
$$-{\frac {4}{ \left( -3+3\,C \right) {C}^{3}} \left( {\it EllipticK}
 \left( {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {C}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {C+1}}}} \right) {C}^{3}-{
\it EllipticK} \left( {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {C}{\frac {1}{\sqrt {C+1}}}}
 \right) {C}^{2}-5\,{\it EllipticE} \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {C}
}{\sqrt {C+1}}} \right) {C}^{2}+8\,{\it EllipticK} \left( {\frac {
\sqrt {2}\sqrt {C}}{\sqrt {C+1}}} \right) C-8\,{\it EllipticK} \left( 
{\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {C}}{\sqrt {C+1}}} \right) +8\,{\it EllipticE}
 \left( {\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {C}}{\sqrt {C+1}}} \right)  \right) {
\frac {1}{\sqrt {C+1}}}}$$

I am trying to understand how Maple can generate these answers, so any help is wonderful for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Techniques for evaluation of elliptic integrals were worked out in the 19th century.  The book I know about is

*Hancock, H.*, [**Elliptic integrals.**](http://resolver.library.cornell.edu/math/2033131), New York: J. Wiley and Sons, 104 S. (1917). [ZBL46.1469.01](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:46.1469.01).

Many years ago I got the softcover reprint of this from Dover.

Hancock spends a chapter or two on evaluating integrals in terms of the standard elliptic integrals $E, F, K, \Pi$.  I can only assume that Maple uses something like these methods.